# What's the purpose of 'initializing' and 'initialized' in OpenZeppelin's Initializable contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

The OpenZeppelin [Initializable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-sdk/blob/master/packages/lib/contracts/Initializable.sol#L31) contract includes a modifier `initializer()` that shows:

```
modifier initializer() {
    require(initializing || isConstructor() || !initialized, "Contract instance has already been initialized");

    bool wasInitializing = initializing;
    initializing = true;
    initialized = true;

    _;

    initializing = wasInitializing;
}
```

1. Why is the point of introducing `initializing`?
2. Why is `initialized` placed before the body of the inserted code? Shouldn't it be only set to `true` at the very last step?

Comment: You can find the answer from https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/whats-the-purpose-of-initializing-and-initialized-in-initializable-sol-contract/11092.